# Draw a Tree/Lattice with VBA using an Array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a binomial tree for option evaluation, and I want to draw a lattice using values that comes from an array where values are already there.

So basically I have an array in my VBA that ressemble to this:

[My array in vba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89pMa.png)

And I want to paste in an Excel sheet in this form:
[How i want to paste in my worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWqH6.png)

I don't necessarily ask for a code, I would just like to have an idea of the algorithm  used to create the tree. I really tried to see any pattern and couldn't find.

What I identified is that if the number of columns of the array is (n+1), then then number of rows will be (2n-1).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does each successive column in the array have 1 more item than the column before it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The array is 2 dimensionnal but is filled as if it was a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you an idea. You would need to tweak it if your array is not 1-based:

```
Sub InsertTree(Nodes As Variant, RootNode As Range)
    'Assumes that Nodes is a 1-based array
    'That has data 1-element in its first
    'column, 2 in its second, etc. And that RootNode
    'Has been chosen so that there is enough room
    'for the tree
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim TopNode As Range 'top node in each column

    n = UBound(Nodes, 2)
    Set TopNode = RootNode

    For j = 1 To n
        For i = 1 To j
            TopNode.Offset(2 * (i - 1)).Value = Nodes(i, j)
        Next i
        If j < n Then Set TopNode = TopNode.Offset(-1, 1)
    Next j
End Sub
```

As a test, I set my spreadsheet up so that beginning at A1 I had:

```
a b d g
  c e h
    f i
      j
```

Then I ran:

```
InsertTree Range("A1:D4").Value,Range("F10")
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]